# Marketo duplicated form validation

Tags: forms, marketo

I have a problem with duplicated Marketo Form. I have 2 exactly the same forms on a page. First one is displayed in the content section of the page, the second one is diplaying in a popup when some button is clicked.

The issue is that when I submit the first form which is blank the validation messages are displaying for the second form in a popup.

I understand that the problem is that 2 forms have the same ID.

Is there a way to have 2 exactly the same Marketo forms working well on a page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the Marketo form is embedded, it gives the `<form>` element a unique ID attribute based on the form ID. When you put the same form on the page twice, it puts two `<form>` elements on the page with the same unique ID, and - apart from that being invalid HTML - it means when you submit one form, it tries to submit both forms.

I'm not sure if it is possible - but there may be a way to use javascript to dynamically alter the `<form>` ID after it has been loaded into the page, therefore giving you two separate unique IDs... YMMV!

The only other workaround I've used was to duplicate the form in Marketo, and have a 'form A' and 'form B'.

Comment: Thank you! That is one of possible options.